# Occurrence in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
create table #Task (ID int, Name varchar(1), Occurrence int)

insert into #Task values (1, 'A', 2)
insert into #Task values (2, 'B', 3)
insert into #Task values (3, 'C', 1)
insert into #Task values (4, 'D', 2)

select * from #Task
Go
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question? You did not ask anything here.

Comment: Seriously 2005 ?

Comment: What are you using unsupported versions of SQL Server?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2):

One option uses a recusive query:

```
with cte as (
    select id, name, occurrence from #task
    union all
    select id, name, occurrence - 1 from cte where occurrence > 1
)
select id, name from cte order by id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=54fef7b9f20d0b4826899dc20f79fa64)**:

```
id | name
-: | :---
 1 | A   
 1 | A   
 2 | B   
 2 | B   
 2 | B   
 3 | C   
 4 | D   
 4 | D
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got a table with numbers in it (which can be used for other tasks, too):

```
select t.ID, t.Name
from #Task as t join numbers as n
  on n.i between 1 and t.Occurrence
```

Simple search for "create numbers table" on how to create this numbers table.

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d94e512aa37141bf491ed1cffefb62f)